# How to process a UK Visa if the owner of the business died

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

We own a business but it is named after my dad who just passed away this year. My mom, my siblings and I are the ones who are managing it at the moment. The transferring of names from my late dad to us may take a while. This is the only source of income that we have.

How can we apply for a UK visa with this kind of situation?

Comment: If he would be still alive, how would you proceed? I do no understand the problem Same money, same family, similar documents. Or before that, you had a salary, and now you are a co-owner without salary?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi given that we categorize ourselves as self employed since we own a business,can we still use his business permit with his name on it since he is the owner to comply for the requirements of the UK Visa?

Comment: If it's legal for you to keep operating the business with his permit, then UK visa office isn't going to care.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi can we still use his papers like business permit,ITR,DTI permit since all of the papers are still in his name? And just explain to the cover letter about it and attache like my dad's death certificate to support this?

Comment: @DJClayworth it is legal here in the Philippines as long as we inform the authority and that the government knows about the situation.We are also currently transferring his assets into our names but it may take a while for it to be done.

Comment: For me yes. It is family money, and you show you have strict contact with family. Note: on various countries (which ask UK visa) only the husband own money, but for visa reason you consider one large pot which can be used for wife, children and other relatives.).

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm wondering if a cover letter (with an explanation about this) together with his death cert,business permits,etc with his name in it are enough ???

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Oh and one more thing,since me,my mom and my siblings works for my dad's business should we indicate "employer" or "self employed"? We basically co-own the business but on legal papers like business permit,ITR,etc only my dad's name is written.

Comment: Do you have a fix salary? Then employees. What do you write on your taxes? You take too much weight on (non-UK) official papers (which are never consistent between countries). Try to answer about reality. Are you using businesses money to make the travel or from your own salary? Finally you should prove you can afford the travel, and that you will not remain in UK, and this is what they will check. What documents do you have to prove that? If the business gives you regularly money into your bank account: employee, else not, or it will just confuse officers.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions.  Putting on hold for now.